# Presence at the SDR & Ham Radio devroom at FOSDEM'24

Tags: discussion

Does anyone want to drop by and say hello? Do we have a dedicated presence / Birds-of-a-feather meeting (we might want to coordinate that with the Belgian hams)?

I'm attaching the call for presenations below, I don't think I could improve an overview of what is happening in Brussels next year.

---

> ##### Dear Friends of Free and Open Source Radio!
>
> FOSDEM 2024, the Free and Open Source Developer’s Meeting taking place in
> Brussels, Belgium, 3. & 4. February 2024, will once again feature a track on
> FOSS-powered Radio; this year, there will be a combined Amateur Radio and SDR
> Devroom:
>
> https://fosdem.org/2024/schedule/track/radio/
>
> In case you're wondering what Amateur Radio and Software-Defined Radio are, we
> have a small introduction below. See the "Recommended Topics" section!
>
> We invite developers and users of Free Software from these fields and to
> contribute to this event by presenting their projects, ideas and their work.
>
> Please read our Call for Presentations below:
> See you in Brussels!
>
> Bastien, Marc and Marcus
>
> ## Submit Your Presentations!
>
> To suggest a talk, go to
>
> https://pretalx.fosdem.org/fosdem-2024/cfp
>
> "Submit a proposal" and fill in the fields; make sure it's in the Software
> Defined Radio and Amateur Radio track!
>
> ### Content and Shape of Presentations
>
> Please aim for your talk to be 20 to 25 minutes long, which leaves enough time
> for questions & answers within a 30 minute slot. Should you definitely need
> more time, we can combine time slots; but please reach out to us before
> submitting your overlength talk proposal!
>
> The final schedule will be available through Pretalx and the official FOSDEM
> website. Notice that the reference time will be Brussels local time (CET).
>
> In the Software Defined Radio and Amateur Radio devroom, we aren’t constrained
> to holding slideshow presentation – bring your demo, your prototype! However,
> since this is a software community conference, please refrain from offering
> marketing-style presentations. Give the radio experts something to chew on! We
> like the nitty-gritty technical details.
>
> ### Travel Aid
>
> If you are a young person, and cannot afford to travel to Brussels and stay
> there, please do contact us as early as possible with an itemized estimate of
> your financial needs, and remark that you've done so in your proposal's
> "Submission Notes". The International Amateur Radio Union Region 1 has
> generously offered to assist financially for up to two contributors.
>
> ### Recommended Topics
>
> Topics discussed in the devroom include, but are not limited to:
>
> - SDR frameworks and the tools that make them useful
> - New SDR-based developments in ham radio modes
> - Cellular/telecom software
> - Amateur radio operator software tooling
> - Free / Open radio hardware
> - Wireless security research
> - Entertaining wireless hacks
> - SDR & ham radio in mass and higher education
> - Satellite, spacecraft and interplanetary communication
>
> Software-Defined Radio is the technology of enabling radio signals to be
> processed and generated algorithmically,  typically within general purpose
> processors, but also within FPGAs and GPUs; Free and Open Source (FOSS)
> Software Radio allows these  algorithms to be inspectable and improvable. With
> the advent of ubiquitous IoT, sky-filling satellite megaconstellations and
> 5G/6G as standards designed with commercial Software Radios in mind, wireless
> is an exploding field of interest in the FOSS realm.
>
> Ham Radio, also known as amateur radio, is more than just a hobby orbiting the
> usage of radio communication – it's a passion that merges the realms of
> electronics, human interaction, and communication. At its core, ham radio is
> about establishing connections: with people, with technology, and with the
> world at large. It is a free and open community effort at heart!
>
> ## Important Dates
>
> - Submission Deadline: 1. December 2023
> - Announcement of selected talks: 15. December 2023
> - Conference: 3. & 4. February 2024
>
> ## Organizer's Contacts
>
> - Software-Defined Radio & Amateur Radio Matrix Space:
>   https://matrix.to/#/#fosdem2024:c1.uba.be
> - Devroom Chat:
>   https://matrix.to/#/#sdr-and-ham-radio-fosdem24:gnuradio.org
> - Amateur Radio Program Committee:
>   Bastien Cabay, ON4BCY on4bcy@uba.be, Marc Balmer, HB9SSB marc@msys.ch
> - Software-Defined Radio Program Committee:
>   Marcus Müller mmueller@gnuradio.org
>
> You can also find this announcement on
> https://gnuradio.org/news/2023-11-08-FOSDEM24-CfP
> should you want to share it.